# Bulk Email notifications in Java?

Tags: java, api, email

I have written a service which uses the Java Mail Api to send bulk email notifications to the recipients. I feel that the way I implemented the solution is not really scalable when the number of recipients increases. I would like to know if there is a better way to make my solution more efficient.

This is what I tried so far

```
@Component
public class EmailService {


     public String  sendEmail(String [] to,String from, String subject, String msg) throws MessagingException {

         String status ="099";
         final  String password ="********";

           final String fromsender = from;
            Properties props = new Properties();  
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");     
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
               protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
               return new PasswordAuthentication(fromsender,password);  
           }  
           });  

           //session.setDebug(true);  
           Transport transport;
        try {
            transport = session.getTransport();
             InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(fromsender);  

               MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
               message.setSender(addressFrom);  
               message.setSubject(subject);  
               message.setContent(msg, "text/plain");  
               //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  
               for(int i =0;i<to.length;i++){
                   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[i]));  


               }

               transport.connect();  
               Transport.send(message); 
               status ="000";
               transport.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return status;
        }
```

Comment: If the list of recipients is very huge, you should consider to configure an e-mail alias or a mailing list address, and left the task to the mail server.

Comment: Another consideration about the recipients list is when the list is very long, it is not so useful for the recipient to have such e-mai: he/she can replay to all! Maybe over certain number, you can consider to send the e-mail individually.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you show the necessary `import` lines, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It's not mandatory, but it really helps!

Answer (score 2):

#### Indentation

Please please please please **automatically indent your code**. You're doing all readers (and yourself) a disservice by not following indentation conventions and enforcing them through your IDE.

#### Abstraction

This code can be much cleaner by simply extracting responsibilities into methods, especially those that encapsulate setup. Let's get the code into a final state as follows:

```
public String sendEmail(String[] to, String from, String subject, String msg) throws MessagingException {
    String status = "099";
    final Session session = buildMailSession(from, password);
    final MimeMessage message = buildMailMessage(session, from, to, subject, msg);
    final Transport transport;
    try {
        transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect();
        Transport.send(message);
        status = "000";
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (transport != null) {
            transport.close();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

This is signifcantly easier to comprehend and understand. It even makes clear, what `status` is. You should very much consider extracting those into named constants.

This is a good moment to also talk about documentation.

When extracting methods, that is a huge opportunity to include some "free" documentation through the method name. In case that is not sufficient, one should employ *javadoc" to clarify what the method does exactly:

```
/**
 * Sends an email to all the recipients in <tt>to</tt>
 * 
 * @return {@link #SUCCESS_STATUS} if sending was successful,
 *     {@link FAIL_STATUS} otherwise
 */
public String sendEmail(..);
```

#### Signature changes

Instead of returning magic Strings, it would be much cleaner to return an enum value like so:

```
public SendResult sendEmail(...) {
    SendResult status = SendResult.SEND_FAIL;
    // ...
         status = SendResult.SEND_SUCCESS;
    // ...
    return status;
}
```

Now if we use the fact that I introduced a `finally` block, which is executed regardless of how the corresponding `try`-block is left we can simplify this to:

```
public SendResult sendEmail(...) {
    // ...
        Transport.send(message);
        return SendResult.SEND_SUCCESS;
    } catch (..) {
    // ..
    return SendResult.SEND_FAIL;
}
```

In addition to that you should consider changing the signature to the following:

```
public SendResult sendEmail(String msg, String subject, String from, String... to)
```

This makes use of "varargs" to allow invoking it as follows:

```
emailService.sendEmail(message, subject, from, "recipient@example.com", "recipient2@example.com");
```

Whether that's more useful... How would I know?